# Difference between Update method and FixedUpdate in Unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, rigid-body-dynamics

i am starting to learn Unity3d and one of the confusion i get is difference between `Update()` and `FixedUpdate()`.

I am following Lynda Unity 2D game development tutorial there, the instructor uses `Update` method, the player has RigidBody2D component and Box collider, he uses the `Update` method to translate the player, but when i do same in `Update` the player doesn't move but when i do it in `FixedUpdate`, everything works. He is giving tutorial from Unity 4.3 and i am taking the course in Unity 4.6.

Where should i use `Update` and `FixedUpdate`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was going to write this as a comment, but it ended up being rather long winded so I've turned it into an answer.

The current answers are mostly correct, but a few things mentioned are misleading/wrong.

In general, *most* game-play related tasks will go in `Update`.

For example, you don't want to be polling for input in `FixedUpdate` (not because of performance, but because the calls simply won't work correctly). AI falls in the same boat.

*Continuously* updated physics are the *only* gameplay related task that `FixedUpdate` should be used for. *Non-continuous/once-in-a-while* calls to things like `Physics.Raycast`, or even `Rigidbody.AddForce` belong in `Update`. My mention of `Rigidbody.AddForce` is seemingly contrary to what might be implied by the documentation, but the key is Continuous vs Non-continuous.

One huge reason why only continuous physics belong in `FixedUpdate` is the actual nature of `FixedUpdate`. Other answers have mentioned how FixedUpdate is called at a fixed `interval, but that's slightly misleading. In reality, a script is passed a time in Time.deltaTime`/`Time.fixedDeltaTime`* which doesn't correspond directly to the actual time between calls, but rather the *simulated* time between calls.

(*`Time.deltaTime` and `Time.fixedDeltaTime` are the same value when called in `FixedUpdate` [Unity is able to tell if the current call to `Time.deltaTime` originated during `FixedUpdate` and returns `Time.fixedDeltaTime`])

Naturally the same way `Update` can't be called in a constant manner because of varying performance, neither can `FixedUpdate`. The key difference is, each frame, if `FixedUpdate` hasn't been getting called often enough to average out to the correct interval between calls, it gets called multiple times (or isn't called the average is too high). This is what the [docs on Execution Order](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) refer to in saying that FixedUpdate can be called multiple times a frame:

> ...  FixedUpdate: FixedUpdate is often called more frequently than Update. It can be called multiple times per frame, if the frame rate is low and it may not be called between frames at all if the frame rate is high...

This doesn't affect Physics because of the nature of the rest of the execution order and the engine, but just about anything else you put in `FixedUpdate` will be affected, and it will cause issues.

For example, if you put AI processing inside `FixedUpdate` there's no reason to assume that the AI won't skip updates for multiple frames in a row. Additionally, each time `FixedUpdate falls behind, your AI will update multiple times in a single frame before things like physics and player input/movement are processed, which is a waste of processing at the very least, but is also extremely likely to cause hard to track down bugs and erratic behavior.

If you need to do something at a fixed interval use other methods Unity provides such as `Coroutines` and `InvokeRepeating`.

And a small note on `Time.deltaTime` and when to use it:

The easiest way to describe the effect of Time.deltaTime is it changes a number from unit per frame, to unit *per second*. For example, if you have a script with something like `transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 5)` in Update, you're essentially moving the transform at a rate of 5 meters *per frame*. That means if framerate is low the movement is slower, and if framerate is high, the movement is faster.

If you take that same code and change it to `transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 5 * Time.deltaTime)` , the object is being moved at a rate of 5 meters *per second*. That means no matter the framerate, the object will move 5 meters every second (but the slower the framerate, the jumpier the object's movement will appear since it still moves the same amount every X seconds)

In general, you want your movement to be per second. That way no matter what speed the computer is going at, your physics/movement will behave the same way, and you won't have strange bugs popping up on slower devices.

And there's no point in using it in `FixedUpdate`. Because of what I mentioned above, you'll get the same value each call (the Fixed Update Timestep value), and it won't do anything to your values. Movement/Physics defined in `FixedUpdate` is already going to be in units per second so you don't need it.

Answer (score 4):

The `Update` function is called every frame. Its frequency depends on how fast the computer is able to render images. On a slower computer, `Update` is called less frequently than on a faster one. If you do time-based calculations, you can normalise them using `Time.deltaTime` which tells you how long it has been since the last time `Update` has been called (caveats apply).
You will generally use `Update` to perform display-related tasks (e.g. updating a UI element)

The `FixedUpdate` function is called at fixed intervals. No matter how often the image refreshes, `FixedUpdate` will be called `1/Time.fixedDeltaTime` times per second
You will generally use `FixedUpdate` to perform gameplay related tasks (e.g. updating physics)

Comment: Is this an alternative to multiplying by Time.delta time? Is there a reason to use one or the other?

Comment: @Ben they have two different goals and you should use the correct function for what you are doing.

Comment: @Lohoris Sorry, I meant is there a reason to use FixedUpdate over Update and multiplying things by Time.deltaTime to make them frame independent?

Comment: @Ben yes, precision. In a system with slow rendering, `Update` gets called less and less often, and your simulation will suffer a lot from that. You might not notice while the simulation is simple, but it will easily break horribly when it isn't.

Comment: @Lohoris Doesn't multiplying by Time.deltaTime fix that, though? Wouldn't FixedUpdate also get called less if the rendering time is huge?

Comment: @Ben no: if you want your simulation to be precise, you have to take many small steps, not huge ones randomly bigger or smaller every time. And no, the whole point of FixedUpdate is that it gets called that many times, no questions asked.

Comment: @Ben: If your calculation have any kind of acceptable error (and they do, since you're using at least one float), then doing calculations based off something you don't control like the framerate will introduce unpredictable errors over time. Unpredictability is generally bad.

Answer (score 2):

From: http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate

The time-step used in FixedUpdate is not variable.

If your game starts to lag, when it catches up, you don't want >10seconds of physics in one update, so it is typically done in FixedUpdate which is called on a fixed-interval.

For example:

```
Update(float elapsedSeconds)
{
  Position += Velocity * 34.23423; //Windows Update is self-important
}
FixedUpdate(float elapsedSeconds)
{
  Position += Velocity * 0.0166; //60fps
}
```

Where:

```
Update(34.23423)

==

FixedUpdate(10.0)
FixedUpdate(10.0)
FixedUpdate(10.0)
//4.23423 + 5.76577 game-seconds later...
FixedUpdate(10.0)
```

Comment: I mentioned this in my answer, but `FixedUpdate` isn't actually called at a fixed interval. The actual nature of `FixedUpdate` is to squeeze multiple cycles of physics into one frame if your game starts to lag and skip cycles if it's going too fast so that the average works out to the Fixed Update Timestep. Unity isn't multi-threaded, so there'd be no way to guarantee FixedUpdate calls at a fixed interval (What happens when one FixedUpdate takes too long). Even if it was it'd probably still be near impossible.

Comment: Most [Unity?] people aren't aware that Render/Update/FixedUpdate are all invoked from within a single callback method, so I conceptualized. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 2):

`Update` is called as fast as possible. The variable 'Time.deltaTime' is set to the actual amount of time that passed since the last call. If lag or something similar slows down the game, `Update` will still be called only once once the lag is over, with a high value of `deltaTime`.

`FixedUpdate` is called at regular intervals. It will never be called more often than the ratio specified in 'Time.fixedDeltaTime'. If lag or something similar slows down the game, `FixedUpdate` will be called multiple times in quick succession to enable the game to catch up. `Time.deltaTime` is set equal to `Time.fixedDeltaTime` before `FixedUpdate` is run, but this is just a fudge to make it easy to migrate code between the two.

Generally, `Update` should be used for interpolable behaviours and `FixedUpdate` for behaviours that must be computed step-by-step, or that depend on those that do, such as physics based movement. If you are writing any kind of loop in `Update` along the lines for `for(time=0;time<=deltaTime;time+=someStep)...` then you should probably be doing it in FixedUpdate instead.